# iOS App Crashes Only in Ad Hoc with NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, ad-hoc-distribution

My iOS app is crashing only when it is deployed (ad hoc) – I've tested the app locally, and there never seems to be the same issue.  It has to do with sending an HTTP Post request.

This is the crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000c18bbec8
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

And this is the code:

```
 NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest new];
    [request setURL:addURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // setup the request headers
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:holder];

 NSURLResponse * response = nil;
    NSData * receivedData = nil;

    receivedData = [NSMutableData data]; 

    // this next line throws an error
    receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Any ideas of why the app is crashing (or any tips for trying to debug the deployed version of the app?)

Here is the full crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: 65D7C33B-D082-4E78-9F73-4489D528AC8B
CrashReporter Key:   8722e51d4300c003d1ac939808b1a9c67f112194
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,1
Process:             [] [200]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5EE4D0E6-303F-4EF3-8C81-489A74425679/[].app/[]
Identifier:          edu.self.[]
Version:             1.1 (1.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-09-26 19:57:39.918 -0400
Launch Time:         2014-09-26 19:57:31.383 -0400
OS Version:          iOS 8.0.2 (12A405)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000001d111bec8
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019591a964 __kill + 8
1   []                              0x000000010010c404 CLSSignalHandler + 224
2   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00000001959b0958 _sigtramp + 64
3   []                              0x00000001000ca954 -[EditProjectViewController addStep] (EditProjectViewController.m:231)
4   []                              0x00000001000cb2a4 -[EditProjectViewController prepareForSegue:sender:] (EditProjectViewController.m:369)
5   UIKit                           0x0000000189902fc4 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 188
6   UIKit                           0x000000018936ce64 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
7   UIKit                           0x000000018936ce64 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
8   UIKit                           0x0000000189355fbc -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 608
9   UIKit                           0x000000018936c800 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 588
10  UIKit                           0x000000018932c294 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 8532
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184b6e384 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
12  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184b6b310 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 356
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184b6b6f0 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
14  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184a99660 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
15  GraphicsServices                0x000000018dbdb5a0 GSEventRunModal + 164
16  UIKit                           0x000000018939e4f4 UIApplicationMain + 1484
17  []                              0x00000001000cd2c8 main (main.m:17)
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000195802a04 start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195900c94 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001957e897c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 272
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001957db4a0 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019591bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b5390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b4fa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019591bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b5390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b4fa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019591bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b5390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b4fa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195900e7c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195900cf4 mach_msg + 68
2   []                              0x00000001000fca00 CLSMachExceptionServer + 128
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b7e7c _pthread_body + 160
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b7dd8 _pthread_start + 156
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b4fac thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019591bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b5390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b4fa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019591bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b5390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b4fa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195900e7c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000195900cf4 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184b6d804 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184b6b758 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184a99660 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018459a054 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 436
6   Foundation                      0x0000000185a82608 __NSThread__main__ + 1068
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b7e7c _pthread_body + 160
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b7dd8 _pthread_start + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b4fac thread_start + 0

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019591b498 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184b731fc __CFSocketManager + 656
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b7e7c _pthread_body + 160
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b7dd8 _pthread_start + 156
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001959b4fac thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000001   x3: 0x00000001958315e4
    x4: 0x000000016fd49928   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000a50
    x8: 0x0000000199477360   x9: 0x000000019946b050  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x000000000000000f
   x12: 0x0000000000000001  x13: 0x000000000003dbd4  x14: 0x0000000000000015  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000025  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000000000000b
   x20: 0x0000000000000003  x21: 0x000000016fd49928  x22: 0x000000016fd498c0  x23: 0x00000001001766f0
   x24: 0x000000017805b1e0  x25: 0x0000000178053ad0  x26: 0x000000017804f5d0  x27: 0x0000000178053ad0
   x28: 0x000000017822cc00  fp: 0x000000016fd49890   lr: 0x000000010010c408
    sp: 0x000000016fd49840   pc: 0x000000019591a964 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: Please provide the full symbolicated crash report. As a note already: never use `sendSynchronousRequest` on the main thread! Never ever.

Comment: what do you recommend using instead?

Comment: use sendAsynchronousRequest instead. Try building in release configuration and see if it happens

Comment: I used sendAsynchronousRequest and get exactly the same issue. Any idea how to fix that in general?

Answer (score 2):

In release builds, if the UI receives input that it cannot handle for more than about 2 seconds, it kills the app. I bet that is what happened in this case.